# Combining multiple dataframes side by side and renaming them

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple data frames in my analysis. For example dataframe 1 where this is the number of people by activity in China

```
Activity            No of people
Activity 1              100
Activity 2              200 
Activity 3              300
```

and data frame 2 where this is the number of people by activity in Amercia

```
Activity            No of people
Activity 1              400
Activity 2              500 
Activity 3              500
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
              ------China Analysis------America Analysis
Activity            No of people           No of people  
Activity 1              100                      400
Activity 2              200                      500
Activity 3              300                      500
```

I thought of doing a merge left on these 2 data frame but how am i gg to do the header? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

If `Activity` are indexes in both dataframes use:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=('China Analysis','America Analysis'))
```

If not, first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Activity'), 
                df2.set_index('Activity')], 
                axis=1, 
                keys=('China Analysis','America Analysis'))
print (df)
           China Analysis America Analysis
             No of people     No of people
Activity                                  
Activity 1            100              400
Activity 2            200              500
Activity 3            300              500
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it :

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame({'Activity':['Activity 1', 'Activity 2', 'Activity 3'], 'No of people':[100,200,300]}).rename(columns={'No of people':('No of people', 'France')})
table2 = pd.DataFrame({'Activity':['Activity 1', 'Activity 2', 'Activity 3'], 'No of people':[101,201,500]}).rename(columns={'No of people':('No of people', 'America')})
table3 = pd.DataFrame({'Activity':['Activity 1', 'Activity 2', 'Activity 3'], 'No of people':[566,22,38]}).rename(columns={'No of people':('No of people', 'Espana')})

merged = table1.merge(table2, on='Activity').merge(table3, on='Activity')
merged = merged.set_index('Activity')

merged.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(merged.columns)

print(merged)
```

It outputs :

```
           No of people               
                 France America Espana
Activity                              
Activity 1          100     101    566
Activity 2          200     201     22
Activity 3          300     500     38
```